# My code is not working? Code Glitch?

Tags: java

The code is supposed to cycle through all the numbers until it finds two numbers that can fulfill the conditions:

The factor of the number must consist of half of the original numbers digits
And the factor numbers must not be a multiple of 100. PS. the factor numbers are T and H.

However the code is not working

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VampierSlayer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input A Even Digit Integer");
        int i = S.nextInt();
        String iS = Integer.toString(i);
        int t = 0;
        int h = 0;
        for (h = 0; h < 1000000000; h++) {
            if (h * t == i && iS.length() / 2 == Integer.toString(h).length()
                    && iS.length() / 2 == Integer.toString(t).length() && h % 100 == 1 && t % 100 == 1) {
                System.err.println("Finish");
                break;
            } else {
                t++;
                h = h - 1;
            }
            if (t > 1000) {
                t = 0;
                h = h + 1;
            }
            System.out.println(t + " " + h);
        }
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(h) + "," + t);

    }

}
```

Comment: Ah, `VampierSlayer` should be `VampireSlayer` of course :). On a more serious note: what is the problem? What doesn't work? Vampires aren't getting slayed?

Comment: The problem is that if i input a number... ex 1260: The program should return 21, 60. But the program does not do that. 21 and 60 are the only numbers to fulfill the conditions

Comment: So what *does* it do instead? What happened when you debugged through the code line by line to ensure it worked as you expected?

Answer (score 1):

First, you're iterating through all numbers in a bit inconsistent way, you won't get all possible `t-h` combinations that way. Much better way would be to use 2 nested for-loops:

```
for (int h = 0; h < ...; h++) {
    for (int t = 0; t < ...; t++) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Next, you should do some research about how modulo works, you should have

```
h % 100 == 0 && t % 100 == 0
```

to properly check that numbers `t` and `h` are multiples of 100.

Answer (score 0):

"And the factor numbers must not be a multiple of 100." Doesn't this mean:

```
    if (h * t == i && iS.length() / 2 == Integer.toString(h).length()
                        && iS.length() / 2 == Integer.toString(t).length() 
&& h % 100 != 0 && t % 100 != 0)
```